# Facebook Page - Latest Stories Posted?

Tags: facebook, fbml

Not sure if this is possible. I want to grab the latest X stories posted to a facebook page wall and embed them into an external site - preferably with PHP. Something like the latest tweets but with a facebook page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is definitely possible using the PHP Facebook API client.

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.get

To do this you will need an API key (obviously).

using the Client Library you'll just need to call:

```
$stream = $facebook->api_client->stream_get($viewer_id, $source_ids, $start_time, $end_time, $limit, $filter_key, $metadata);

foreach($stream as $wallpost)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($wallpost);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

where
$source_ids = the page
$limit = the limit of posts you want
$viewer_id = the id of the viewer, obviously someone with viewing permission of the wall.

Comment: This seems to be what I am looking for. I havent defined $facebook, is the php library supposed to do this? I'm getting that error

Comment: Figured it out, had to put my facebook api key and secret key into the inline file.

thanks!

Comment: Sorry, was behind a restrictive firewall at work. Darn thing keeps me from going into facebook's api docs. Glad you figured it out though :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to take a look at [Facebook Connect](http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php).